# How to do performance testing with 5 users creates 5 tickets using visual studio or J meter performance testing tool

Tags: visual-studio, jmeter

Provided 5 users credentials and ticket data in 5 rows of excel sheet and associated that data in performance script. If i need to do load testing with 5 or more virtual users. Then is that mean five users will create 5 tickets or each user will create 5 tickets .

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you configured. following are the simulations and their results:

1. 5 users, 1 iteration: all 5 users create one ticket each (user1 -> tkt1 etc).
2. 5 users, 2 iterations: all 5 users create 2 tickets each and both are same. (user1 -> tkt1 & user1 -> tkt1 etc).
3. 10 users, 1 iteration: all 10 users create 1 ticket each. (user1 -> tkt1 & user6 -> tkt1) npte. here, tickets will be shared among threads.

Note: CSV data is shared by the threads. Once all entries are consumed, threads start picking the data from the beginning again, unless you set `Recycle on EOF` to false (by default, true)

Comment: This is helpful reply. So if we add virtual users and 5 number of rows in csv file (4 columns and 5 rows) then 5 users will create 5 tickets.Like ticket 1, ticket 2 , ticket 3 ...ticket 5 .. is it right? Can u help toknow where can we set configuration in visual studio load test tool

Comment: Yes, user1->tkt1, user2->tkt2 etc. If any of the file entries got consumed fully, then counter is set to the beginning row of the file. You can try it out with a small set of dataset (5 users and 5 rows) and observe the behaviour using View Results Tree. I'm sorry as I don't have knowledge in Visual Studio.